# Nested web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I was looking through my companies web application that was developed in .NET 2.0. 
On deployment they have nested web application created under "default web site" as in the structure below

- Default Web Site

  - My Root Application

    - Sub Application 1
    - Sub Application 2
    - Sub Application 3

Every application is a .cs project. Many of the sub applications are even just having a single web service(approx. 15-20 web methods) and nothing more.

As the guys who developed this project are not around I was wondering 
Q1. what was the reason to take this approach? Was there some limitation on IIS and .NET 2.0 that made them have this structure.

Q2. If I wanted to merge all of them into one single web application. Is it recommended?

Q3. What are the advantages and disadvantages of such web application nesting? when to nest web app and when not to?

I am sorry If this post is appears in the wrong section of stack overflow. If so please guide me in posting it in the right section.

Thanks in advance for all the help and suggestions.

Comment: I think the general rule is... ain't broke don't fix it.
What you can do is create a different solution and try to build the same thing from scratch with the architecture you think would work better.

Comment: IMO, everything has pros and cons. Splitting means no dependencies, if a single web app goes down, it won't affect other web apps. However, it's more difficult to maintain/extend/diagnose etc.

Comment: Thanks Alex,kienct89. Nothing is broken but the site run's only on IE(because of using Activx, .htc etc) and its on 2.0 framework. No more this site can be loaded on modern browsers.There is a roadmap to upgrade to newer .net versions, make it work. Should I propose to have all under one web app? What is the general suggestion or following? web application is not very huge and usage is not like a ecommerce site etc. receiving thousands of hit.

Comment: I agree with Alex - there can be numerous reasons this was made so. Many that don't necessarily involve bad decisions. Ask the question: what is the value for your company of you refactoring this? If none, don't bother. I know it can suck to maintain something, that's not as pretty as you want it to be - in that case, make sure you have other projects, where you can do your thing, and be glad that you are able to tell the difference :) Best of luck, bro.

Comment: Oh, and *if* you want/need to refactor it - based on your description (relatively small website and all), I would start from clean slate and then move stuff over / reimplement as needed. More fun than fixing old stuff and you get to do it exactly as you want

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite broad, without knowing, what are those sub-applications, how, or if, they communicate with each other, and so on. But splitting things apart is usually a good practice. In your particular case: the sub-applications can be better scaled, when you run them on several machines. You get even better maintenance, as if you have to fix something, you deal then with some **discrete** part of your big application. The architecture should be much better, as when it was possible to split the applications into several sub-application, it means, they are **loosely coupled**.

In our web applications, we always have usually 3 Web-Projects: API, Web, CMS. I'm not counting here other Business Logic Layers, DAL, etc. So now, we can run them as separate instances, as you have, but we can also run them as one application, we must just specify the routings: API `myapp.example/api/**`, CMS: `myapp.example/cms/**` and Web: `myapp.example/**`.